# Is there a css alternative for for background-attachment: fixed for a background image set to cover

Tags: css, css-position, background-image, cover

I have a `<div>` with a full screen background image for my slides. Due to a package I can't use `background-attachment: fixed;`. Without this property my image is distorted and in the slides. I can't use `background-attachment: fixed; here.

```
<div ref={parallaxDiv} className="image" />

.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/people") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Is there an alternative for `background-attachment: fixed;` for a background image set to cover?

Comment: cover shouldn't distort your image, only crop it at either the sides or top/bottom so it fits. Could you make a snipppet with an actual image so we can see the problem for ourselves.

Answer (score -1):

does this work for you

```
.image {
 background: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/people");
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
```